# Can a Jenkins install use different paths for binaries and jobs, artifacts?

Tags: jenkins

I'm installing Jenkins (on Windows) and would like the installation itself -- `jenkins.war`, `jenkins.exe`, plugins, to be on the system drive (C:), but the jobs and artifacts -- on D:

The [documentation for `JENKINS_HOME`](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/backup-restore/jenkins-home) seems to suggest, that *is not possible*... Is that correct, or is there a separate variable -- or command-line switch -- I can use to tell the software to use separate paths for "code" and "data"?

Comment: Check out the top answer on this thread. I don't think you can change the default output location but you can set up tasks to copy builds elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890952/where-are-jenkins-artifacts-located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a documented option to separate the "**code**" (ie: `jobs/jobname/config.xml`) from the **data**" (ie; `jobs/jobname/builds/...`)

Use Jenkins Sytem Property [jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-buildsdir).

`jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir`

> Default:
> `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds`
>
> Description:
> The configuration of a given job is located under `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/[JOB_NAME]/config.xml` and its builds are under  `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/[JOB_NAME]/builds` by default. This option allows you to store builds elsewhere, which can be useful with finer-grained backup policies, or to store the build data on a faster disk such as an SSD. The following placeholders are supported for this value:
>
> ```
> ${JENKINS_HOME}  – Resolves to the Jenkins home directory.
> ${ITEM_ROOTDIR} – The directory containing the job metadata within Jenkins home.
> ${ITEM_FULL_NAME} – The full name of the item, with file system unsafe characters replaced by others.
> ${ITEM_FULLNAME} – See above, but does not replace unsafe characters. This is a legacy option and should not be used.
> ```
>
> For instance, if you would like to store builds outside of Jenkins home, you can use a value like the following: `/some_other_root/builds/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` This used to be a UI setting, but was removed in 2.119 as it did not support migration of  existing build records and could lead to build-related errors until restart.

Read additional details following the link about how to achieve for an existing configuration.

> **Usage**
>
> System properties are defined by passing `-Dproperty=value` to the java command line to start Jenkins. Make sure to pass all of these arguments before the -jar argument, otherwise they will be ignored.
> Example:
>
> `java -Dhudson.footerURL=http://example.org -jar jenkins.war`
>
> **Caveat: Compatibility**
>
> We do **NOT** guarantee that system properties will remain unchanged
> and functional indefinitely. These switches are often experimental in
> nature, and subject to change without notice. If you find these
> useful, please file a ticket to promote it to an official feature.

ps: I don't know of a "ticket to promote it to an official feature", but I'd upvote any such request.

The above properties are counter-intuitively (ie: JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS):

System properties are defined by passing `-Dproperty=value` to the java command line to start Jenkins. Make sure to pass all of these arguments **before** the `-jar jenkins.war` argument, otherwise they will be ignored.

The basic sequence is:

`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -jar $JENKINS_WAR $PARAMS`

---

I should also direct you to a related answer on Serverfault: [Jenkins [networking] configuration parameters are to be used when installing or when running jenkins?](https://serverfault.com/a/1081820/189417). There are specific "code" related options to point to different directories. The following are "$PARAMS" to the war, so come **after** the `-jar jenkins.war` parameter.

Relevant summary listed below, but check your binary for options.

```
C:\apps\j2>java -jar jenkins-2.303.2.war  --help
Running from: C:\apps\j2\jenkins-2.303.2.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Jenkins Automation Server Engine 2.303.2

Options:
Usage: java -jar jenkins.war [--option=value] [--option=value]
   --webroot                = folder where the WAR file is expanded into. Default is ${JENKINS_HOME}/war
   --pluginroot             = folder where the plugin archives are expanded into. Default is ${JENKINS_HOME}/plugins
                              (NOTE: this option does not change the directory where the plugin archives are stored)
   --extractedFilesFolder   = folder where extracted files are to be located. Default is the temp folder
   --logfile                = redirect log messages to this file
   --javaHome               = Override the JAVA_HOME variable
   --toolsJar               = The location of tools.jar. Default is JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
   --config                 = load configuration properties from here. Default is ./winstone.properties
   --commonLibFolder        = folder for additional jar files. Default is ./lib
   --extraLibFolder         = folder for additional jar files to add to Jetty classloader
   --usage / --help         = show this message
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the `--webroot` and the `--pluginroot` to point at a folder under `C:\Jenkins\`, while `JENKINS_HOME` points at `D:\Jenkins\`... It is almost, what I was looking for. Sigh, Jenkins is a Java-program, written by Java-programmers...

Comment: Fully agree; Jenkins uses a bizarre/simplistic/lazy layout. Would have expected they follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html), which would have the binaries in `/opt`, config in `/etc/opt` and data in `/var/opt`, etc. "The use of /opt for add-on software is a well-established practice in the UNIX community", or so you'd think. The storing of logs (and ArchiveArtifacts) in with the job config is highly annoying and complicates backups.